# EC2: network id of created EC2 is not same as in subnet IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, subnet

I create a window EC2 in subnet having CIDR as 172.31.64.0/20 and checked the IP address of created EC2 machine in cmd prompt, the IP address is 172.31.74.131

but as per my understanding Net id should be same as subnet id
what could be the reason of this.[image: IP address of Subnet][image: IP address of created EC2]
could anyone suggest please
Please refer the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

As it is part of the `/20` range this covers 4,096 addresses in a range from `172.31.64.0` to `172.31.79.255` (in which range your host IP lies).

A useful tool for the future to help plan CIDR ranges is [cidr.xyz](https://cidr.xyz/).

Comment: Thanks it is really helpful because I am new to AWS

Comment: Thats no problem, everyone has to start somewhere :)